# Membership.GetAllUsers() gives error "Item has already been added"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'am using the Membership provider and now facing the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '0859929000'  Key being added: '0859929000'

The Key is the UserName from the aspnet_Users table, which has no duplicates.

This code generates the error:

```
private void BindUsersToUserList()
{
    // Get all of the user accounts
    MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    UserList.DataSource = users;
    UserList.DataBind();
}
```

All users are imported manually by me using the stored procedures `aspnet_Users_CreateUser` and `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser`.

Now, the question is, where is the problem?
Is there anywhere else in the database duplicates might occur (tables, corrupt indexes etc.) and cause this problem?

Comment: Even better, can someone provide me with the actual sql statement the GetAllUsers() method executes?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

There were duplicates in the LoweredUserName column. I missed that somehow.